# Apache appears to be running the wrong version of PHP for phpMyAdmin

Tags: apache-httpd, upgrade, php, phpmyadmin

OS: Linux Mint 18.3

I am using phpMyAdmin 4.5.4.1. This is the most recent version as per Synaptic.  But I wanted to install a more recent version so I downloaded and extracted 5.0.1 and hopefully put it in the right place (/usr/share), renaming the old directory and renaming this one "phpmyadmin".

"local/phpmyadmin" then fails to work in the browser: I get the message:

```
PHP 7.1.3+ is required. 
Currently installed version is: 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.7
```

So then I went and upgraded PHP to 7.4. This is now the system version.

But I'm still getting the same message when I attempt to go to "localhost/phpmyadmin".  I have checked my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file: there's nothing there about a flavour of PHP. The last line of this file is

```
include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

... so I checked that too: again, nothing obvious about a choice of PHP other than the system version.

I also located all the php.ini files for PHP 7.4:

```
/usr/lib/php/7.4/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/7.4/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/7.4/php.ini-production.cli
```

... I seemed to remember than one of these maybe has to be copied and renamed "php.ini", so I copied php.ini-production to "php.ini". No doubt this has to be tweaked, but I'm not sure it's relevant to phpMyAdmin.

Has anyone got any idea where the stipulation of a particular version of PHP might be made for phpMyAdmin?

PS I also tried installing phpMyAdmin using a couple of PPAs: both gave me a message saying "This PPA does not support xenial" (Linux Mint 18.3 ==> corresponds to Ubuntu Xenial).

Comment: You mention Apache, what method are you using to serve PHP through Apache?  `mod_php`? `php-fpm`?  something else?

Comment: Thanks. Gulp, I have no idea. How would I know that? I just installed the package phpmyadmin using apt-get.  Ditto Apache. PHP 7.4 installed using a PPA.

Comment: The I believe the usual default PHP option through Apache is usually with `mod_php`, which would mean that you are tied to whatever version of PHP that `mod_php` was built with.  You should be able to check if that is the case by running `apache2ctl -M | grep -i php`.  If this turns out to be the problem, you would need to upgrade the `libapache2-mod-php` package from the same repository you installed PHP 7.4 from.